# how to call another visualforce page from an apex command button

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, commandbutton, action

I have an Apex command button in my Visual Force page. Using that button I want to call another visual force page, which in turn should call action function written in the controller.

Please advise.

Comment: You want to navigate to another VF page and execute action function in its controller or just call the action function from another VF's controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the below code in the controller action method that is being called on click of command button

```
PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/yourVFPageName');
pr.getParameters().put('key','value');
pr.setRedirect(true); // If you want a redirect. Do not set anything if you want a forward.
return pr;
```

**Edit:**
<s>In the constructor of the 'yourVFPageName' page controller you can call any method.</s>

As **@Vigneshwaran G** has mentioned:

use action attribute in page to call that method. Otherwise if the method being called from constructor contains any DML statements it will throw error.

Comment: If the method being called from constructor contains any DML statements it will throw error. So use action attribute in page to call that method.

Answer (score 2):

visual force page code:

```
 <apex:commandButton value="button" action="{!redirect}"/>
```

in the controller define this function:

```
public PageReference redirect()
{
   PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/yourVFPageName');
   return pr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

visual force code:

```
<apex:commandButton value="redirect" action="{!redirect}"/>
```

controller:

```
public PageReference redirect() {
    return Page.existingPageName;
}
```

Advantage of declaring this way is:

> PageReference for a Visualforce page that has already been
>   saved in your organization. By referring to a page in this way, the
>   platform recognizes that this controller or controller extension is
>   dependent on the existence of the specified page and will prevent the
>   page from being deleted while the controller or extension exists.

[PageReference Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm)